# Print Plugin for Tinymce not working using WAMP

Tags: tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and for some reason the plugin's do not work. I have downloaded the lates version of tinymce and using the following code.

```
<script src='../tinymce/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script src='../tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tinymce',
        branding: false,
        height: 500,
        plugin: "print", //I have also tried ['print'],
        toolbar: "print", 

    });
</script>
```

I have checked the print plugin is in the plugins directory as well.

I am using WAMP the latest version on their site as well. Could it be a WAMP setting that prevents this?

If I use the following I get the buttons but still not the print one:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tinymce',
        branding: false,
        height: 250,
        plugin: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'formatselect | ' +
            ' bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            ' bullist numlist outdent indent |' +
            ' removeformat | help pagebreak print',

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the configuration option to load plugins is `plugins` not `plugin` so I don't believe that you are actually loading the plugins you think you are as you are using the wrong key for that option in the configuration.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/basic-setup/#pluginconfiguration

From that documentation page here is an example:

```
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',
 plugins : 'advlist link image lists'
});
```